# Handsontable V 7.4.2 will work on Angular 1.8?

Tags: angularjs, angular, handsontable

I want to know Angular V 1.8 and Handsontable V 7.4.2 both combo will work or not. I have searched many sites and docs, But I didn't get a proper answer.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Phix before getting started I just want to know is it possible, I think communities like StackOverflow can help me out, I will be helpful if already anyone tried this.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific issues with code already written. Be the first to try!